# DisposedObjectException after closing DockContent document

Tags: dock, docking, dockpanel, dockpanel-suite

I am seeing so odd behavior with `DockPanelSuite` when I close my documents.  When I click the close `'X'` at the top right of the documents the top document closes as expected `(calls FormClosing event and Dispose() method of my derived DockContent class)` but a small tab remains from the document.  It is like the `DockContent` realizes the content should be discarded and ditches all the internal controls and the Form.Text is gone from the tab, and what remains is a tiny tab w/o any text.

Further attempts to close the tab again or click on the tab result in an `'ObjectDisposedException'.`

Here are my environment specs:

```
Visual Studio 2008
DockPanelSuite AssemblyVersion("2.5.0.*")
Windows 7 x64
```

Below is a stacktrace.  Stepping into the code I can see it bombs out when it tries to get the `IDragSource.DragControl` which is an instance of my already disposed control

```
(control being a derived DockContent class):

at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
at WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockPanel.DragHandlerBase.BeginDrag() in C:\Users\nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\DockPanel\WinFormsUI\Docking\DockPanel.DragHandler.cs:line 48
at WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockPanel.DockDragHandler.BeginDrag(IDockDragSource dragSource) in C:\Users\nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\DockPanel\WinFormsUI\Docking\DockPanel.DockDragHandler.cs:line 699
at WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockPanel.BeginDrag(IDockDragSource dragSource) in C:\Users\nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\DockPanel\WinFormsUI\Docking\DockPanel.DockDragHandler.cs:line 811
at WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockPaneStripBase.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) in C:\Users\nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\DockPanel\WinFormsUI\Docking\DockPaneStripBase.cs:line 195
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockPaneStripBase.WndProc(Message& m) in C:\Users\nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\DockPanel\WinFormsUI\Docking\DockPaneStripBase.cs:line 246
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
at MosaicMaker.Program.Main() in C:\Users\nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MosaicMaker\MosaicMaker\Program.cs:line 18
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Besides this minor hiccup I am thoroughly pleased with the library.

Comment: If possible, please use the latest release from http://dockpanelsuite.com. Besides, a picture can explain better what is "but a small tab remains from the document." Unless you reveal more information regarding the problem, it is rather hard to diagnose based on what you have typed.

Comment: Since you have answered your own question, please accept it and mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out my code was the source of the problem.  The problem occurs when a control on a DockContent form throws an exception in its Dispose() method.  The control does not dispose correctly, and for some reason the DockContent control does not close correctly.

Comment: The thrown exception interrupts the closing process.  This should be expected as the dispose pattern should _never_ anticipate an exception to be thrown.

Comment: If you know of FxCop and Mono Gendarme, you should be aware of the rules that catch such violations, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386039.aspx